# Create PK for #temp table failed when the script is run in parallel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following code in a stored procedure.

```sql
....
select ... into #temp from ....
alter table #temp add constraint PK_mytemp13 primary key (....)
....
```

And I will get the following error message from time to time if the stored procedure is run in parallel.

> There is already an object named 'PK_perf322dsf' in the database.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I think it can be avoid by the following approaches. Is there any other more elegant solution?

1. Create a temp table with primary key first. Then insert the rows.
   `create table #temp (... primary key (....))`
2. Create PK dynamically with session id dynamically.
   `declare @s varchar(500) = 'alter table #temp add constraint PK_temp' + @@spid + ' primary key (....)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. you try to insert to the **same** temporary table from **different** connections (which is impossible, instead of global temp tables),
2. or you try to insert into **different** tables.

if 2nd - you simply may do the following - ALTER TABLE #temp ADD PRIMARY KEY(...)

if 1st - you have to create the table (regular or global temporary) with key prior to use it in parallel operations

Comment: This error has to do with creating a local temp table, making a named primary key in a block of code and having more than 1 connection calling that block of code.  SQL Server doesn't allow 2 PKs with the same name, even in local temp tables.

Answer (score 15):

This can only happen if the same client connection instantiation (which equals one SPID or connection in SQL Server) is being re-used for 2 different calls. Two parallel calls should have different connection instantiations and separate SPIDs

SPIDs are completely isolated from each other with local (single #temp tables)

Edit:

Ignore above

I've never named constraints on temp tables before. I use indexes as I need them or just add PRIMARY KEY after the column. Constraint names are database-unique in sys.objects

A PK is basically a non-unique clustered index. So use `CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX` instead as index names are unique *per table* in sys.indexes.

This fails when run in 2 SSMS Query windows

```
CREATE TABLE #gbn (foo int NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE #gbn ADD CONSTRAINT PK_gbn PRIMARY KEY (foo);
```

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
>   There is already an object named 'PK_gbn' in the database.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Curiously, the error and the constraint name match unlike your error

This works

```
CREATE TABLE #gbn (foo int NOT NULL);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_gbn ON #gbn (foo);
```

Comment: @MartinSmith: from the error, the constraint name is being ignored. IIRC, when I've created indexes (not PKs mind you) on temp tables then a lot of underscores and some hex is added. I've never had a concurrency problem. I'd suggest the error isn't around temp table handling

Comment: named constraints still have to be uniquely named in `tempdb` as they are unique in `sys.objects`. Named indexes don't have to be. Actually the OP should probably just use a unique index or an unamed constraint. (Edit: See what you mean about the error message though...)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Just verified it. See update. I've never thought about using named constraints on temp tables. Always do on persistent tables though

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to remember how to do this, but you can create a nameless primary key on a temp table and avoid this error.  This is different than putting a column-level PK, as it supports more than 1 column.  Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
  AccountNumber INT NOT NULL,
  TransactionNumber INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (tranid, sys_process_dt)
);
```

This allows the end goal plus prevents name duplication.  Querying will show that SQL Server will put a GUID in the name of the PK for you in sys.sysobjects:

```
SELECT *
FROM tempdb.sys.sysobjects
WHERE name LIKE '%#test%'
```

name |                          xtype

--------------------------------

#test___..._000000000407 |     U

PK__#test_____B88A05A770B3A6A6  |    PK

You can have your cake and eat it too.

Answer (score 2):

Even more to the point, ANY named constraint on a temp table must be uniquely named across sessions. This also means that a default constraint (say you're setting a field to default to a value of -1) and that default constraint is explicitly named, SQL Server will throw an error when you attempt to create a temp table in another session window even though it's not a key constraint.

For example, open two query windows and run the following code in one and then the other (without closing either window first):

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTbl1;
    CREATE TABLE #TempTbl_1 (
             [TestCol1] INT 
            ,[TestCol2] BIGINT CONSTRAINT [DF_Tc2] DEFAULT (-1)
        );
```

The first window will execute fine, but the second will throw an error stating

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
There is already an object named 'DF_Tc2' in the database.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

This is in spite of the fact that the table has no PKs or indexes, just a named default constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered and accepted but still did not see the correct point has been call out.

when you create Named constraint, name of the constraint has to be precise at table level. they are scoped at database level. so either do not create named constrained and let sql pick its own name or if you give name make sure it s unique in that DB. even for TEMP DB.